# Mapping a DB column to a custom object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework (schema first) and generating my model from the database. Let's say I have a column like `FrequencyHz`, where I store the a frequency value, in hertz. The DB column is a long.

When I generate the model, it makes a `FrequencyHz` property of type Long. What I'd like to do is create a custom class called `Frequency` that takes in a `long hertz` and does some conversion / formatting stuff (e.g. converting to other units). I can define a class that does the math, but I'm not sure how to configure Entity Framework / model generation to map to this custom class.

In the properties dialog in Visual Studio, I don't seem to have a way to map the column to a type other than built in primitives.

I'm on  EntityFramework version="6.2.0", targeting .NET 4.5.2.

Comment: EF6 doesn't support conversions. EF-core does.

Comment: Do I need to be on. Net Core to use EF core?

Comment: No, but don't move to EF-core without thoroughly testing if it supports all of your current application code. It's still got many issues.

Comment: That's a damning statement, especially considering that EF Core 3.0 was just released *today*.

Comment: @madreflection Yep, from previous experiences with EF releases I expect EF 3 to have issues as well, although they made significant progress in query translation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating a table from database then EF does not support mapping of your table to custom class...

You have to use the default table then do calculation on top of it and bind to other custom object or class.

If you want then you can use code first approach where you have the flexibility to write your own type of class with lots of customization...